# How long does it take until a cow gives birth in Harvest Moon: A New Beginning?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

My cow is pregnant but it still hasn't had the calf. And when I go up to her it says she has a maternal look in her eyes. I would really love it if I could get a anwser. Because I'm a little stuck. :(

Comment: Ummmm . . . What game are you playing?

Comment: That is a very good question. A good answer cannot be given if we do not know what game this is from. Could you please re-tag and re-ask to format it with the game in it?

Comment: OK, I had to do a little Google Kung-fu, but I figured it out and tagged this as harvest-moon-anb.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://fogu.com/hm11/farm/cows-and-yaks.php, it will take 20 days to give birth to a calf. It will have half the hearts of the mother.