# How long does it take for a calf to be full grown in Harvest Moon A New Beginning?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

How long does it take for a calf to be full grown in Harvest Moon A New Beginning?
And for that fact, what about the other animals? (chicks, sheeps, you get the deal)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Calfs and other animals take 20 days to grow up after they are being born.

Comment: What source do you have for this?  That's the same amount of time as it takes for one to be born, so that seems somewhat off.

Comment: The answer is 20 days. Period. Play the game yourself if you don't believe me.

Comment: Hi Assylum, if you feel you are being harassed by other user(s), it is indeed important you contact either the community moderators or [Stack Exchange](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/contact). In the meanwhile - and this applies to anyone here - please keep the comments here on-topic. For the moment I've deleted/edited the comments already here.

Answer (score 5):

According to this [source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/645735-harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning/wiki/3-1-caring-for-livestock-and-chickens), cows have a pregnancy period of 21 days, followed by another 20 days until adolescence. While the source is somewhat incomplete, I would hazard a guess that sheep and alpaca have the same pre-adolescent period since they share the same pregnancy period of 21 days.

Chickens, on the other hand, have an incubation period of 7 days (since you put eggs in the hatcher, rather then get them pregnant), followed by 8 days until adolescence.

Note that this source is incomplete for higher quality breeds such as Jersey cows and Silkie chickens, but from my experience with previous games in the series (such as *Tale of Two Towns*), they should share the same pregnancy/incubation/adolescence period as the base livestock.

Comment: I'm guessing the duration of pregnancy listed on that site includes the day you impregnated the animal, which would explain the difference between that and [my answer here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/148031/how-long-does-it-take-until-a-cow-gives-birth-in-harvest-moon-a-new-beginning/148037#148037)